# Python Dictionary For Rays Baseball Players

Tags: python

Step 4 is what I really need an answer for.

1. Make a dictionary for nine Tampa Bay Rays that are given. Use the player names as keys and a list for each value. **This is what I have:**

   ```
   rays_players = { 'DeJesus': ['DH', 6, 299],
            'Loney': ['1B', 4, 222],
            'Rivera': ['C', 9, 194],
            'Forsythe': ['2B', 5, 304],
            'Souza Jr': ['RF', 2, 229],
            'Longoria': ['3B', 3, 282],
            'Cabrera': ['SS', 7, 214],
            'Kiermaier': ['CF', 1, 240],
            'Guyer': ['LF', 8, 274] }
   ```
2. Each value list should hold the position played by the player, the batting order, and current batting average. **See above**.
3. When the dictionary is complete, use a for loop to display the dictionary keys and values. This is what I got for this: **This is what I have:**

   ```
   for key in rays_players:
       print(key, rays_players[key])
   ```
4. Next, use loop(s) to print the "lineup" (the dictionary in batting order). **How do I make a order for this?**

   ```
   for key in sorted(rays_players.items(), key=lambda v: (v)):
       print ("%s: %s" % (key))
   ```

   **Is this on the right track at all?**

   Step 4 is supposed to look like this:

   ```
   Batting 1: CF Kiermaier, current avg: 240
   Batting 2: RF Souza Jr, current avg: 229
   Batting 3: 3B Longoria, current avg: 282
   Batting 4: 1B Loney, current avg: 222
   Batting 5: 2B Forsythe, current avg: 304
   Batting 6: DH DeJesus, current avg: 299
   Batting 7: SS Cabrera, current avg: 214
   Batting 8: LF Guyer, current avg: 274
   Batting 9: C Rivera, current avg: 194
   ```

Comment: What is your question? I actually only see some assignment. The dictionary initialization looks alright. What else have you tried and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: I'm just starting out with Python, and really have no idea how to do loops, the examples I read just dont make sense to me, making the dictionary seemed pretty straight forward so I did that.

Comment: Your assignment explicitly mentions for loops. Have you tried to go through any tutorials? For example take a look at this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop but there are many others. If you don't understand any particular concept, ask about it. However SO isn't  a coding service. You should show some effort.

Comment: I actually just read something about a for loop for part 3 and inputted that, which made sense to me. Not sure if I did it correctly though. I edited my post.

Comment: Just really confuwsed about the batting order thing. Idk how to make it sort by the middle value.

Comment: You only get one question per question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. Reworded it for one part.

Answer (score 3):

Partly you may be making the problem more difficult by adopting an inappropriate format for your data (don't worry, beginners often do this). So you might want to ask yourself if a dictionary is the most appropriate structure.

Your sort at step 3 is headed the right way, but for the element `key` you want to sort on the batting order, which is `key[1][1]` (btw, this is a poor choice of variable name as you are iterating over the items of the dictionary).

You should find this serves to sort and print your batting order:

```
print "Rays Starters"
for key in sorted(rays_players.items(), key=lambda v: (v[1][1])):
    print ("%s: %s" % (key))
```

This doesn't make the sort key terribly obvious, though, so you might wish instead to define a simple class that allows you to reference the player attributes by name like this:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, position, order, average):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
        self.order = order
        self.average = average
```

You can then keep the players in a list as follows.

```
players = [Player('DeJesus', 'DH', 6, 299),
           Player('Loney', '1B', 4, 222),
           Player('Rivera', 'C', 9, 194),
           Player('Forsythe', '2B', 5, 304),
           Player('Souza Jr', 'RF', 2, 229),
           Player('Longoria', '3B', 3, 282),
           Player('Cabrera', 'SS', 7, 214),
           Player('Kiermaier', 'CF', 1, 240),
           Player('Guyer', 'LF', 8, 274)]

print "Rays Starters"
print "Rays Starters"
for p in sorted(players, key=lambda v: v.order):
    print ("Batting %s: %s %s, current average %s" % (p.order, p.position, p.name, p.average))
```

That not only makes it a little more obvious that you are sorting on the batting order, it also allows you to pick out the individual attributes as you need them.

Another way to do the formatting is using the newer `.format()` string method (it is definitely backported to 2.7, but I don't know if it's in earlier Python 2 releases):

```
print "Rays Starters"
for p in sorted(players, key=lambda v: v.order):
    print ("Batting {0.order}: {0.position} {0.name}, current average {0.average}".format(p))
```

As far as updating the running order goes, I presume you need to find a specific player by name rather than simply knowing whereabouts they appear in the list.

Here's a little helper function that will return the correct list index for a player with a given name:

```
def find_player(name):
    for n, player in enumerate(players):
        if player.name == name:
            return n

print "Longoria is element number", find_player('Longoria')
```

The `print` statement should display

```
Longoria is element number 5
```

You can then use this to alter the player list in the following way:

```
players[find_player("Rivera")] = Player('Wilson', 'C', 9, 152)
players[find_player("DeJesus")] = Player('Beckham', 'DH', 6, 200)

print "Rays Starters"
for p in sorted(players, key=lambda v: v.order):
    print ("Batting {0.order}: {0.position} {0.name}, current average {0.average}".format(p))
```

giving the output

```
Rays Starters
Batting 1: CF Kiermaier, current average 240
Batting 2: RF Souza Jr, current average 229
Batting 3: 3B Longoria, current average 282
Batting 4: 1B Loney, current average 222
Batting 5: 2B Forsythe, current average 304
Batting 6: DH Beckham, current average 200
Batting 7: SS Cabrera, current average 214
Batting 8: LF Guyer, current average 274
Batting 9: C Wilson, current average 152
```

Comment: Thanks for all the input, but I need the players in a dictionary with the players names as keys. and a list for each of the values. A lot of helpful info here regardless though.

Comment: Agree with @holdenweb here, a dictionary with key of player name is a very poor structure. Why exactly do you think “I need the players in a dictionary with the players names as keys”? Knowing the answer to this will allow us to help you.

Comment: I agree as well, but the question is asking me to write it like this to learn about dictionaries. Lists was covered earlier. Think thats why it is confusing me. If anyone could just help me with step 4 it would be helpful. I edited my post

Comment: This way makes more sense to me since I have seen it, but I still need to do it the distionary way somehow.